# How to find official Android Studio older versions?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-version

I have some issues on Android Studio latest versions (3.5). I think it is not stable. How do I download older versions which stable?

Comment: FYI. Latest stable AS version is 3.5.2.

Comment: check your laptop or pc specification, at least your have 6 gigabyte ram. Especially, you should make sure the version before download such as version Canary, Beta and Stable

Answer (score 6):

In these links you can find all releases:

- [**Android Studio download archives**](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive)
- [AS latest stable version](https://developer.android.com/studio/)
- [AS latest preview version](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can download all the old versions here: https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

Answer (score 0):

As of today i am using Android Studio 3.5.1 and it is very much stable.

You can post the issue what you face with current stable version. So that folks can help you with that.
As Google recommend latest stable version to use.

However you can find older one here https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

Answer (score 0):

You can be download of latest version is [Android Studio Stable Version 3.5.2](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/11/android-studio-352-available.html)

Answer (score 0):

Now **official older version** of Android Studio isn't available but you can download it from some third party websites.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34406687)